# Advantages of Java vs Python for 2D Graphics, user scripts

Tags: java, python, graphics, scripting, user-input

**Disclaimer:** I dont want to encourage a "My Java is better than your Python" debate here. I am writing both languages myself and like them, I know both languages have their advantages, and it is those advantages I want to know about here, nothing else.

I have been thinking about building a game for a while now, and I was wondering if Python or Java would be better suited *for the things I want to do*.

It would be a 2D strategy game, a bit like [Frozen Synapse](http://www.frozensynapse.com/) but without the fancy graphics and the turn-based aspect. The game would pit two Players against each other, who have no way to influence the game after it started (So, technically, it would be more of a simulator than a game). Both players would input a script they wrote for their armies that tells them what to do. For example:

```
On EnemySpotted:
    contact Units in Range
    find cover
    move to cover
    open fire

On Contacted:
    If Contacted for(enemy spotted):
        Move in range
        find cover
        open fire
...
```

The scripting language would of course look a bit different, but you get the idea.

So, basically, I would require the following things:

1. 2D Graphics
2. Input, parse and apply user Scripts
3. Network communication

I know that Java can do 1 and 3 pretty easily, and the same goes for python. So, is there a difference between Java and Python in applying user input, can one language do it in a painless way, without massive `if`-blocks? What would be the recommendation on what language to use?

I know that you will most likely say "Use whatever language you are most comfortable with", but a few pointers to useful functions, libraries and / or frameworks of both languages would still be great.

Comment: Any special reason to -1 this? I know it's a pretty broad question, but I tried to be as exact as possible about what I want to know.

Comment: "Disclaimer: I dont want to encourage a "My Java is better than your Python" debate here." But there is realistically nothing else the question can accomplish.

Comment: @Karl but there is. I am asking for decent frameworks, useful functions and all that. If I would just ask "Which language is better", that would maybe encourage such debates, but that's why I avoided a general "which one is better" in favor of a "name a few useful functions or frameworks". What else can I do?

Comment: *"What else can I do?"* Lots of research, followed by asking more specific question**s** based on that research.  If this question is not argumentative, it is at least too broad.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Well, I was trying to get a few pointers what I should take a look at. There are so many different engines, libraries and frameworks, and I had hoped for a few people to give a recommendation which ones are actually working. I'm not asking you to do my research, I'm just looking for places to start. If questions like this aren't wanted here, I'll remember that the next time and only ask actual programming questions here, no problem, but I did not know that this kind of question is not welcome here.

Answer (score 2):

I do see any problem with the second requirement making game in Java. You have at least:

- Groovy
- Jython
- Rhino

to enhance you software with scripting capabilities. I can't really advice you if its better using Java or Python, because I mainly work with Java (using Python mainly for small helper programs to work with console), just giving you examples of scripting capabilities which can be integrated within you Java application.